# How to make RecyclerView's grid item to have equal height and width?

Tags: android, grid, android-recyclerview

I define my `RecyclerView` as grid by setting its layout with `GridLayoutManger` that has a span count of 3 which are already working fine. I also add an item decorator to my recycler view which will manage the spacing between grid items, this also works fine.

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My implementation for adding item decoration to my Recycler View:

```
mBuddiesGrid = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.buddies_grid);
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        mBuddiesGrid.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, (int) dpToPx(10) , true));
        mBuddiesAdapter = new BuddiesGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new Buddies());
        mBuddiesGrid.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

My grid item xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Theodore"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

By adding spaces between grid item will adjust the grid item's width which can possibly cause of not getting the proportion size of my item view. What I want to obtain is to resize my grid item height equal to its width dynamically. How can I do it?

Comment: I've copied your `GridSpacingItemDecoration` and it works great!

Answer (score 45):

I've done this using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_black_24dp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: easiest one. Thank you.

Comment: Shit now i point to constraint layout man i works , 
I have a relative layout, there is not form to have equal width. Now put this inside the relative and use android:src=.

I was about to increase the dimensions of the all images svg.Now only with constraintlayout

Comment: The only solution on whole internet that worked!!!..Kudos!!!

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Still works even in 2023!

Answer (score 16):

One way you can ensure equal width/height is to use a custom view which calculates the height based on its width when `onMeasure()` is called. The neat thing with this is that other than creating the custom view, there's no coding involved.

Here's a custom view extending `LinearLayout`:

```
public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        // note we are applying the width value as the height
        super.onMeasure(width, width);
    }

}
```

Here's an altered version of your grid item layout, using the above custom `LinearLayout`:

```
<com.yourpackage.name.views.SquareLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Theodore"/>

</com.yourpackage.name.views.SquareLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may write code in "onBindViewHolder" function in recycler view holder. In that you can get view tree observer of recycler view and change width or(and) height of recycler item view.

Comment: Using the TreeObserver is a last resort and a very hackish solution, using a modified custom layout is far cleaner. Also, modifying the layouts based on listening to the layout tree might result in multiple layout passes.