# Equal Width and Height in RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make something like this.where each item has equal width and height.I set the **width** to `match_parent` and change the **height** dynamically inside `onBindView()`

[image]

here is what I did so far.I tried to get the width of the `cardView` (which is the  container of the item) inside the `onBindView` and assign it to height.
but it always gives `-1` when logging

activity.java

```
 private void setupRecyclerView() {

    categoryRecyclerAdapter = new CategoryRecyclerAdapter(this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryRecyclerAdapter);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemDecorationCategory(5, 2);
    categoryRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

}
```

adapter.java

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Category category = categoryList.get(position);

    int width = holder.cardViewContainer.getMeasuredWidth(); //returns -1
    holder.cardViewContainer.getLayoutParams().height = width;
    Timber.d("width --> " + width);
    holder.cardViewContainer.requestLayout();
    holder.textViewCat.setText(category.getCategory());
    Picasso.with(context).load(category.getResId()).into(holder.imageViewCat);

}
  public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.cardViewContainer)
    CardView cardViewContainer;
    @BindView(R.id.cat_imageView)
    ImageView imageViewCat;
    @BindView(R.id.cat_textView)
    TextView textViewCat;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
 }
}
```

activity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey"

tools:context="com.project.bishoy.lost.category.CategoryActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    tools:listitem="@layout/category_item"

    android:id="@+id/category_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardViewContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:elevation="5dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cat_imageView"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/mob"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cat_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063565/how-to-make-recyclerviews-grid-item-to-have-equal-height-and-width), but it doesn't help

Comment: Create a `SquareLayout ` its also mentioned in the link you have added above

Comment: do you mean I should use `SquareLayout` as the `parent`

Comment: Yeah as root of your list item .

Comment: I think I missed the XML part of the answer. I extended the `ConstraintLayout` and it 's working now

Comment: Bravo ..........