# Equal height and width of RecyclerView items

Tags: android

As you can see from the images below, I have almost achieved what I wanted. However, the `RecyclerView` items don't have equal size. In particular, the 2nd `RecyclerView` column is different in size from the 1st column.

Note that I have tried implementing the solution from [How to make RecyclerView's grid item to have equal height and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063565/how-to-make-recyclerviews-grid-item-to-have-equal-height-and-width), but I couldn't resolve my issue.

[image: Result of my code]

RecyclerView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.jackandphantom.circularimageview.RoundedImage
        android:id="@+id/launcher_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment.java:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(getActivity(), R.dimen.medium_margin));
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```

ItemOffsetDecoration.java

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int mItemOffset;

    private ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
        mItemOffset = itemOffset;
    }

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(@NonNull Context context, @DimenRes int itemOffsetId) {
        this(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(itemOffsetId));
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent,
                               @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        int position = parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view);

        GridLayoutManager manager = (GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();

        if (manager != null && position < manager.getSpanCount()) outRect.top = mItemOffset;

        if (position % 2 != 0) {
            outRect.right = mItemOffset;
        }

        outRect.left = mItemOffset;
        outRect.bottom = mItemOffset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not a problem of `height / width` of `RecyclerView`. It's a problem of your `ItemDecoration`. Try to change your decoration like below:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent,
                           @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

    int position = parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view);

    GridLayoutManager manager = (GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();

    if (manager != null && position < manager.getSpanCount())
        outRect.top = mItemOffset;

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        outRect.right = mItemOffset / 2; // Right offset for left child
    } else {
        outRect.left = mItemOffset / 2; // Left offset for Right child
    }

    outRect.bottom = mItemOffset;
}
```

**Sample Result:** *Equal space on every side*

[image]

Comment: yeah I thought it could be the problem but then i removed ItemOffsetDecoration for the recyclerview and got the same result. I will try your ItemOffsetDecoration code and update here if my problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like you add extra offset to right of rectangle

```
  if (position % 2 != 0) {
        outRect.right = mItemOffset;
  }
```

this condition will work every odd position since the positions in adapter starts with 0. 
Anyway, are you sure you need custom item decoration to add offsets in GridLayoutManager?

Comment: yes thanks for your answer. Practically i was just putting equal space left, right ,top and bottom but the issue was that i was putting only left padding to even column item indexes i.e 0,2 and putting left , right padding in odd column item  indexes i.e 1,3.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, try removing this block and see how it works

```
    if (position % 2 != 0) {
        outRect.right = mItemOffset;
    }
```

You have a grid layout, in your given picture, the top right and bottom right are indexes 1 and 3. You are changing every odd item's offset.

Comment: i was just putting equal space left, right ,top and bottom but the issue was that i was putting only left padding to even column item indexes i.e 0,2 and putting left , right padding in odd column item  indexes i.e 1,3.